# question about htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have file page1.html, i want rename it to page1.php but it must be accessible to old name pag1.html
what rule in htaccess i must write?

Comment: i need "mapping" so page1.html display but it mapping to page1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for Apache's [mod_rewrite RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /
RewriteRule    ^page1\.html$  page1.php
```

(Blatantly stolen then adapted from the Apache [mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#old-to-new).)